# Edit Form in Blazor and OnValidSubmit

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I Have an EditForm in blazor that I implemented 4 weeks ago. Its has validation associated with each input field. Everything was working fine and there were no issues with it. Today however it will not submit for me when I press the save button. If I try to submit the form with empty inputs it will highlight the validations, but when I then press submit it doesn't do anything or throw any errors. If I change the type to OnSubmit it will submit no problem however it will not ask for the validations. I am very confused as I have not changed anything in this page in weeks and it was working fine two days ago..any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated

```
<EditForm Model="@guest" OnValidSubmit="@GuestBooking" class="registerguestform">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.FirstName " class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.FirstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.LastName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>Date of Birth</label>
            <InputDate @bind-Value="guest.DOB" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.DOB" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>Street</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.Street" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.Street" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Town/City</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.City" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.City" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>Country</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.Country" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.Country" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Postcode</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.Postcode" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.Postcode" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.PhoneNumber" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="guest.EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.EmailAddress" />
            @guest.Message
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>Arrival Date</label>
            <InputDate @bind-Value="guest.ArrivalDate" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.ArrivalDate" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>Departure Date</label>
            <InputDate @bind-Value="guest.DepartureDate" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => guest.DepartureDate" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Add" id="guestregisterformsubmitbutton">Register Guest</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Cancel" @onclick="@Cancel">Cancel</button>
    

</EditForm>
```

Comment: Have you looked for any errors in the browser console? Have you put a breakpoint on the first line of the method that handles that valid submit? Need to determine what level of expertise you have with developing in order to go down the right troubleshooting path with you.

Comment: can you post your `@GuestBooking` method?

Comment: I found out the issue was related to an update for visual studio. Thanks for your help